# Laravel save class namespace in a variable or constant

Tags: php, laravel, constants

I have implemented my controller like this:

```
class PayamAPIController extends Controller
{

    const THESIS = \App\Models\Thesis;


   public function getOffers($offerable)
     {
        // does not work
        $entities =  self::THESIS::where('user_id',\Auth::id())->get();
     }
}
```

this is simplifield version of my controller class.

the problem is i cant access the `Thesis` model via constant.

> FatalErrorException in PayamAPIController.php line 27: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)

i need to store my models in constants or variables and use them inside controller methods

Comment: Just do `THESIS::where()->get()`

Comment: I need to reference to the constant and get the model from there

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a constant, just include the reference to the external Class with 'use' statement:

```
use \App\Models\Thesis;

class PayamAPIController extends Controller{
    $entities = Thesis::where('user_id',\Auth::id())->get();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this is my simplified version of controller class, i need to use constants, i would be appreciate if you find a way to access models via constants

Comment: @alex Can you explain why you need to use constants? The use statement would do exactly the same thing, the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use constants, try something like this

```
protected static $model ='App\Models\MyModel';
//in function
$model = (new static::$model)->where('id', $this->id)->firstOrFail();
```

or else like Claudio King mentioned include the `use Model`

Comment: i usually declare them static, and it works. updated answer

Comment: Thanks, your solution work, but you've used property not constant, is it possible to do the job with constant ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. just declate reference to constant in a variable , then call it:

```
 $model =  self::THESIS;
 entities = $model::where('whatever')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare reference to `constant` in a variable , then call it:

```
class SomeController extends Controller 
{
    protected const MODEL = SomeClass::class;

    public function doSomeThing()
    {
        $entities = (self::MODEL)::where('user_id',\Auth::id())->get();  
    }
}
```